# is there a if multisite have posts function?

Tags: multisite

I need a function that checks if the posttype "events" have posts in all of the multisite websites in the network if false do nothing if true return the cross_events(); function.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't but you can use [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) function to switch to a certain site then use regular WordPress function to check if any post on the post type is exists or not.

### For Example

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'wpse167721_check_networkwide_events');

function wpse167721_check_networkwide_events(){
    global $wpdb;
    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // get the original blog id

    // get network sites
    $args = array(
        'network_id' => $wpdb->siteid,
        'public'     => null,
        'archived'   => null,
        'mature'     => null,
        'spam'       => null,
        'deleted'    => null,
        'limit'      => 100,
        'offset'     => 0,
    );
    $sites = wp_get_sites($args);

    foreach($sites as $site){
        // switch to blog
        switch_to_blog($site['blog_id']);

        if(!wpse167721_is_event_exists())
            continue; // skip current iteration and go to the next one

        // Event exists! do whatever you want to do

    }

  // lets switch to our original blog
  switch_to_blog($original_blog_id);

}


function wpse167721_is_event_exists(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event', // change the cpt name here
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );

    return count(get_posts($args));
}
```

**Caution:**
This code will run for every blog in the network on every page load (because it is hooked into `wp_loaded`). If you have a large network then consider batch processing.

*code not tested*

Comment: [Multisite functions lists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WPMU_Functions)